# Ignore \0 chars when writing to file C

Tags: c, arrays, file, fwrite

I am writing simple server - client app. On server side I receive char arrays of data (with const size). However last char array can have empty bytes.

I append recieved array to file in loop. Here is code:

```
char buffer[256];
/* ...  */
FILE *file;
file = fopen(file_name,"ab+");
for (i = 0; i < parts; ++i) {
    if ((length = recv(sockfd, buffer, 256, 0)) < 0) {
        /* recv failed  */
    }
    send(sockfd, "OK", 2, 0);
    fwrite(buffer, 1, 256, file);
}
fclose(file);
```

for example:
... Quisque dignissim turpis sapien, non facilisis risus gravida at. **\00\00\00\00**

Is there any way how to skip last \0 chars? Or do I have to copy last array byte by byte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
fwrite(buffer, 1, length, file);
```

This will only write as much characters as you acutally received. If the extra `\0` are part of the packet it will be written, otherwise not.

If you are receiving the `\0` characters as part of the packet but you don't want to write them, then you'd have to do this:

```
fwrite(buffer, 1, strlen(buffer), file);
```

Comment: Either you use binary, then the zeroes ar part of your buffer, and you must write them. In this case you must send along how many bytes you are sending as part of your protocol. In your exampled it sounded as if you just send strings and have some extra zeroes in your buffer. Or if you already know in advance how much bytes you are receiveing, you must keep track of it by adding up what you `receive`ed, and stop writing after you received all bytes you expecgted.

Comment: Yes you are right. `fwrite(buffer, 1, length, file);` this works like charm. I just need more coffee...

Answer (score 0):

If the return value of the `recv` function is the length of the readed bytes in the buffer, use that instead the buffer size in the `fwrite` call